# Pass filepath to a shell command in vim

Tags: vim

How would I properly 'escape' the following command in vim?

```
:!file=expand('%:r')
```

Basically, I want to do the equivalent of something like:

```
$ file=my_filename
```

So that I can do a subsequent shell command to refer to `$file`. Currently I get this error:

> Press ENTER or type command to continue 
> /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' \ /bin/bash: -c: line 0:` file=expand('test')'

Which I think just basically means that it's not escaping/generating the filename before passing to the shell. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I missed something, but when you run `:!myvar=42` then `:!echo $myvar`, you can see that the variable is not saved, certainly because it is run in two different shell sessions.

To make your variable accessible to every further shell commands, you can use `setenv()`: `:call setenv('myvar', '42')`, or in your case:

```
:call setenv('file', expand('%:r'))
```

Comment: yes, actually the `!file=...` is just part of the command, the rest of the command is static based on that variable. But the other part isn't part of the 'vim problem'.

Answer (score 2):

1. To pass filename/path to shell use command-line specials

   ```
   :!AnyShellCommand %:r
   ```
2. To set environment variable use `:let`

   ```
    " like this
    :let $AnyEnvVar = expand('%:r')
    " or like this
    let $AnyEnvVar = fnamemodify(@%, ':r')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in an [`execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute), for example:

```
:execute  "!file=" . expand('%:r')
```

Comment: In addition, I would use `shellescape()` to ensure that the parameter is valid as a shell parameter: `:execute  "!file=" . shellescape(expand('%:r'))`